# Geochart not working after include the PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

Geochart not working when I included the PHP code.

Below is the code before the PHP added which works fine:

```
  google.load('visualization','1', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
  });
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'LATITUDE');                                
      data.addColumn('number', 'LONGITUDE');
      data.addColumn('string', 'DESCRIPTION'); 
      data.addColumn('number', 'A:', 'value'); 
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'tooltip'});                        

data.addRows([[3.9374,102.3620, 'Jerantut', 0,'tooltip']]); //jerantut,phg

data.addRows([[ 4.7549,103.4156, 'Kuala Dungun', 1,'tooltip']]); //terengganu


    var options = {
      region: 'MY', // Africa
      displayMode: 'markers',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      colorAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: ['#6699CC']},
      sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 25},
      legend: 'none',  
      enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      datalessRegionColor: '#D2F5F4',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    };

     var chart = new   google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
```

Below is the code after PHP code added:

```
function drawVisualization() {var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
        data.addColumn('number', 'LATITUDE');
        data.addColumn('number', 'LONGITUDE');
        data.addColumn('string', 'DESCRIPTION');
        data.addColumn('number', 'A:', 'value'); 

$exec = mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while(echo json_encode( $row );){
data.addRows([['city_lat', 'city_long', 'student_city', 'count']]);
};
```

**Database Structure:**

[image: Database Structure]

Please do let me know what was the fault after the PHP code added and how to sort this out.

**Database in detailed:**

[image: Database in detailed]

**UPDATED**

```
 $sql='select count(`student_city`) as count,
    `city_lat`,
    `city_long`,
    concat(`student_city`, ", ",`student_state`) as `description` 
from marketing_data GROUP BY student_city asc LIMIT 3';
```

Comment: what does the source code look like for the version rendered in PHP? Does the javascript code look correct that is generated?

Comment: the 2nd version of `drawVisualization()` does not call the `data.addColumn` method

Comment: _Stop_ assembling JSON “manually”! Create & fill the appropriate data structure(s) instead, and then use `json_encode` to generate a representation of it that can directly be output as valid JS code.

Comment: According to the documentation: In `Markers Mode` ( which is what you have shown above I believe ) `"The first column is a specific string address (for example, "1600 Pennsylvania Ave").

OR
The first two columns are numeric, where the first column is the latitude, and the second column is the longitude."`

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Could someone help to restructure it into the correct php code as requested ? It will be helpful. And i also have doubt in the colorAxis and sizeAxis because the visualization should be shown on the number of students in each city.

Comment: in the `while` loop rather than build your own json data you could `echo json_encode( $row );`

Comment: Hi Mr Ram. I've edited the code as above, please assist to check. How about the data.addRows?

Comment: sadly you misunderstood - `while(echo json_encode( $row );){` makes no sense. Perhaps the answer below might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess I would say that you could do it like this but I should stress that I could not test this.

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(
        data.addColumn('number', 'LATITUDE');
        data.addColumn('number', 'LONGITUDE');
        data.addColumn('string', 'DESCRIPTION');
        data.addColumn('number', 'A:', 'value');

    <?php
        /*

            Iterate through the recordset
            and add a new row to the datatable
            for each result.

        */

        $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
            printf(
                'data.addRow[ %s, %s, %s, %d ]',
                floatval( $rs->city_lat ),
                floatval( $rs->city_long ),
                $rs->student_city,
                intval( $rs->count )
            );
        }

    ?>

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    var options = {
      region: 'MY', // Africa
      displayMode: 'markers',
      resolution: 'provinces',
      colorAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 0,  colors: ['#6699CC']},
      sizeAxis: {minValue: 1, maxValue:1,minSize:10,  maxSize: 25},
      legend: 'none',  
      enableRegionInteractivity: 'true', 
      backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      datalessRegionColor: '#D2F5F4',
      defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    };

    chart.draw( data, options );
}
```

**update**
looking now at the above after the fact a clear error is obvious with the above. In the loop where `printf` is called `'data.addRow[ %s, %s, %s, %d ]',` omits the braces so it ought to be `'data.addRow( [ %s, %s, %s, %d ] )',` instead.

A working version based upon your code but structured slightly differently:

```
<?php

    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'dbo-user'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';

    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
    $db = new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    /*
        A slightly modified version of original schema
        ----------------------------------------------

        mysql> describe gm_asia_students;
        +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | matriculation | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | prg           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | semester      | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | intake        | year(4)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | city          | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | lat           | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | lng           | double           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | state         | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        | code          | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
        +---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


        mysql> select * from gm_asia_students;
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+--------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
        | id | matriculation | prg  | semester | intake | city         | lat    | lng      | state      | code  |
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+--------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+
        |  1 |        894635 | 404  | 1        |   2020 | Kuala Dungan | 4.7549 | 103.4156 | Terengganu | MY-11 |
        |  2 |        845615 | 303  | 1        |   2020 | Kuala Dungan | 4.7956 | 103.3231 | Terengganu | MY-06 |
        |  3 |        956325 | 808  | 1        |   2020 | Jerentut     | 3.9374 |  102.362 | Pahang     | MY-11 |
        +----+---------------+------+----------+--------+--------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+

    */

    $sql='select 
        `lat`,
        `lng`,
        concat(`city`, ", ",`state`) as `description` 
    from gm_asia_students';
    $res=$db->query( $sql );

    $tmp=[];
    while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() )$tmp[]=$rs;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Google Visualisations:: GeoChart</title>
        <style>

            #chart{ 
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                float:none;
                margin:auto;
            }
        </style>
        <script src='//www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
        <script>
            google.charts.load( 'current', {
                'packages':['geochart'],
                'mapsApiKey':'LEGITIMATE-MAPS-APIKEY'
            });
            <?php
                # create json variable to be consumed by the dataTable
                printf('
                var data=%s;',json_encode( $tmp ) );

            ?>
            function renderchart(){
                var container=document.getElementById( 'chart' );
                var datatbl=new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    datatbl.addColumn('number','lat');
                    datatbl.addColumn('number','lng');
                    datatbl.addColumn('string','description');

                data.forEach( obj=>{
                    let row=[ parseFloat( obj.lat ), parseFloat( obj.lng ), obj.description ];
                    datatbl.addRow( row );
                });

                var options={
                    region:'MY',    // NOT Africa, but South-Eastern Asia!
                    displayMode:'markers',
                    resolution:'provinces',

                    colorAxis:{ minValue:0, maxValue:0,  colors:['#6699CC'] },
                    sizeAxis:{ minValue:1, maxValue:1, minSize:10,  maxSize:25 },

                    magnifyingGlass:{ enable: true, zoomFactor: 7.5 },
                    markerOpacity:0.75,

                    legend:'none',

                    enableRegionInteractivity:true, 
                    keepAspectRatio:true,

                    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                    datalessRegionColor:'#D2F5F4',
                    defaultColor:'#f5f5f5'
                };

                var chart=new google.visualization.GeoChart( container );
                    chart.draw( datatbl, options );

                container.addEventListener( 'click', (e)=>{ console.info( getSelection() ) } );
            };

            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( renderchart );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='chart'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work Mr Ram. Empty page shown and no error.

Comment: Mr Ram, I've attached database in detailed screen capture which consist of the data in the table. I hope it will be helpful. I'm having doubt on colorAxis: and sizeAxis min and maxValue. I think that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr Ram for your help. Your second code works alike gem. Thanks a lot for your time and your effort to solve this issue. Have a nice day ahead.

Comment: Hi Mr Ram. I've added count query in the code, but it doesn't work as per requested. Anything wrong in my updated code, please refer at the updated code section. I wants to view only 3 cities that has max number of students.

Comment: I think that might be best asked as a totally new question. Be sure to include the table schema and some table data. ( ie: `show create table marketing_data;` - add the create Table code and some data )

Comment: I've changed the code, and I believe it's working now Mr Ram. Thank you so much.